# Alternative to passing userid & password through Java applet?

Tags: java, php, mysql, security, applet

The applet will help the user to create java class objects which will be sent to the PHP server, which will store the object as a blob in a MySQL database. The reverse should work too - reading the data back.

The user will have to be logged into the PHP server anyway to view this applet. But at the same time I don't want to leave the applet 'open' to have access to the database (through PHP) without a password.

The connection will be like this:
Java Applet -- send URL stream --> PHP Script -- Authenticate -- if valid connect to DB --> MySQL DB

I want this process to authenticate the user but at the same time I don't want the user to have to log in again after having logged into the website, and at the same time I don't want the Applet to store any secure information because thats not safe.

Is there a way around here? Or will I have to look for an alternative? (If so, what alternative?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your applet should have the ability to read cookies from the page it is displayed on.  So, assuming the user has authenticated into the webpage, you could have it grab a session ID (or whatever) from the page, and use that to 'authenticate' into your server.  However, bear in mind that unless you're using an encrypted session (https), these cookies can be read in transit by 3rd parties.  Also, you need to be aware that any 3rd party scripts on your page will also be able to read these cookies.

I don't think this is as ideal from a security standpoint as having the user authenticate to the database again, but this is an alternative you can use.

Comment: Provided I won't have any 3rd party scripts on the page, reading the cookies to see if anyone is logged in should be okay though?

Comment: I think the applet doesn't even has to get cookies from the browser. The Java plugin should automatically send the browser cookies with any HTTP request sent from the applet, just as if the request originated directly from the browser.

Comment: Ohh okay, so those could be retrieved from the PHP page with $_SESSION variable?

Comment: The devil is in the details, but yes, user1031312, this is the idea.  In addition to performing basic security checks (ensuring that the user's IP address and/or user-agent hasn't changed since creating the session, etc.), you should probably maintain an activity timer on the session (on the server-side) and timeout inactive sessions, but yes.

Comment: The requests coming from the applet should be similar to the requests coming from the browser directly. They wil be part of the same session. If you don't have any session or if the session is not authenticated, then someone is using the applet without having been authenticated before, or the session has expired because nither the applet nor the browser has sent any request for some time.

Comment: Although I am going to accept this as the answer because of the comments I think it is important for anyone reading this after me to also read @AlexR 's answer below

Answer (score 2):

The applet call should enter the same HTTP session that has already been created by server when user entered the site.

The session is created by server and server sends the session ID as a special Cookie. In case of java based servers it is typically `jsessionid`. The server sends cookies using HTTP response header named `Set-Cookies`. Client should send all the cookies back using header `Cookies`.

So, your applet should be able to access cookies hold by browser and send them. To access cookies of browser you should use LiveConnect API that allows mapplet to call javascript from containing page.

Comment: So you concur with @JB-Nizet ? And btw I have PHP server I don't think my host has JSP

Comment: I have not mentioned any need to write code on server side. It does not matter which server are you using. You can use even ASP if you want. JB-NET's suggestion is very similar to mine.